Referencing a razor page from a Razor Class Library is giving a 404 error
I am trying to reference a razor page contained in a Razor Class Library in a Blazor project. When I go to the route of my page I am getting a 404 error.
Steps to recreate
Create a new solution as a Blazor Web App (.NET 8.0) template.
Add a new Razor Class Library project (Support pages and views checked)
Edit the Page1.cshtml and have the following at the top:
@page "/test"

Add a reference to the Razor Class Library(RazorClassLibrary1) from the Blazor App (BlazorApp1).
In BlazorApp1 edit Routes.razor to be:
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[]{typeof(RazorClassLibrary1.MyFeature.Pages.Page1Model).Assembly}">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

Edit Program.cs of BlazorApp1 to include:
  app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
      .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
      .AddAdditionalAssemblies([typeof(RazorClassLibrary1.MyFeature.Pages.Page1Model).Assembly] );

Start the application and browse to /test and you get a 404. What am I doing wrong?

Why are you trying to use a cshtml defined page?  Use a .razor page.
Here's a Demo project set up as you describe that works.
https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO79028139

RCL should have only components- not pages. Create the page equivalent component and use it in the page of the actual project.

Hi Mayur.  "RCL should have only components- not pages" - not true.  I have full applications defined in RCLs.  One set of pages deployed in both Web Assembly and Server deployments.

By should I meant that as a best practice. You have no visibility into the routes defined in an RCL - unless you have access to the source. But I get where you are coming from - will delete the main reply.

@MayurEkbote Microsoft documentation does NOT agree with you

Routes are not checked at compile time. There is no simple way to check routes used in an RCL. It makes no sense to add routes in a reusable component library. - even if it is allowed.
